# ¿Alguien sabe que fue lo que paso con la moderadora Monica Cellio?

Tags: discusión

He visto últimamente una publicación en destacada en Meta de una persona llamada Monica Cellio donde he visto que muchos de la comunidad se han pronunciado al respecto, alguien puede resumir que fue lo que paso con esta persona?, qué hizo o qué no hizo?

Comment: Te recomendaria leer la que te marque como duplicada, y de ahi seguir todos los hilos (en ingles) de todo lo qeu fue pasando